# How to install GNUPLOT including 'cairo' terminals in the Linux environment without the 'root' permissions?

Tags: gnuplot, cairo

I am installing the GNUPLOT (5.4) under a CentOS environment and don't have the root permission (I am working on a cluster but not a personal workstation). Following the general installation flow,
./configure --prefix=(my path)
make
make install
and add the environmental variables, I plotted a figure. But I ran into a problem as follows,

```
    set term pngcairo font "Arial, 14" enhanced 
         ^
    "plot.plt" line 12: unknown or ambiguous terminal type; type just 'set terminal' for a list
```

,
and then I typed "set term" in the GNUPLOT,
[The all 'terminal' types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfTH9.png). There is no 'pdfcairo' nor 'pngcairo' in the list.
According to my previous GNUPLOT experience, there is no necessity of extra installation of 'cairo' libs through the binary GNUPLOT package in both Windows and Linux systems with the root permission.

I looked through some solutions, one of which is to install the 'cairo' (https://cairographics.org/download/additionaldetailsfordebianderivedsystems/), however, to install the 'cairo', I have to install 'meson', and further I have to update the Python. It seems too complex. So is there a simpler way?

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Bell